# How to convert LinearRing/mesh to face

Tags: modeling

I have many lines, they should be surfaces.
[image: blender shape]
How can I convert all of them to surfaces?

The result should be like this.But there are two 2D polygons.I want two 3D polygons.
[image: 2D result]

Comment: Do you mean your 2 sets of lines should be connected together, or that each individual set of lines should be a polygon ?

Comment: each individual set of lines should be a polygon

Comment: If you just want 1 polygon each, simply select all vertices of a line in edit mode and hit F, but I don't think that's what you're going for.

Comment: I want 1 polygon each,because it's a LinearRing.  The opration 'select all vertices of a line in edit mode and hit F' will create more polygon